# MySQL - best way to retrieve rating and reviews summary from a basic review table e.g. google

Tags: mysql, rating, rating-system

[image: AIM]

I have build a basic table for storing my review & ratings and want to retrieve details for above plugin .

```
review_id | company_id | user_id | rating | review
1           1            1         3        Great
2           1            2         5        Thank you
3           1            3         5        Great
4           1            4         4        Thank you
5           1            5         1        Great
6           1            6         2        Thank you
7           2            5         1        Great
8           2            6         2        Thank you
```

SQL for getting summary

```
SELECT company_id as cid, ROUND(AVG(rating)) AS rate, COUNT(*) AS review_count, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 5 AND `company_id` = cid) AS rating_5,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 5 AND `company_id` = cid) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_5_avg,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 4 AND `company_id` = cid) AS rating_4,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 4 AND `company_id` = cid) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_4_avg,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 3 AND `company_id` = cid) AS rating_3,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 3 AND `company_id` = cid) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_3_avg,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 2 AND `company_id` = cid) AS rating_2,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 2 AND `company_id` = cid) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_2_avg,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 1 AND `company_id` = cid) AS rating_1,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reviews` WHERE `rating` = 1 AND `company_id` = cid) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_1_avg

FROM `reviews` GROUP BY company_id
```

Results:

[image: SQL Results]

I am sure there is a better way (Optimized) to do it but I cant guess so I needed help again.

**Question: How can i optimize it more ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this task:

```
SELECT company_id as cid, 
       ROUND(AVG(rating)) AS rate, 
       COUNT(*) AS review_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `rating` = 5 THEN 1 END) AS rating_5,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `rating` = 5 THEN 1 END) / (COUNT(*) * 100) AS rating_5_avg,
        ... etc 
FROM `reviews` 
GROUP BY company_id
```

Using an aggregate that contains a `CASE` expression:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN `rating` = 5 THEN 1 END)
```

you can obtain a count on a subset of `company_id` records based on the value of `rating` field.

Comment: Thanks for your quick & beautiful answer!

Comment: can you also solve my 1 doubt ? if i use php for getting rating_5_avg will it increase performance/speed or mysql is best fit in this role ?

Comment: @AZinkey i doubt it makes much difference whether you use mysql, JavaScript or PHP, but what not try for yourself